# SQL query extracting first few characters

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a column in my 'abc' table called 'phones'
I need to select everything from the table but only for the people with '520' area codes and the the format for the phone numbers are like so : (540)333-4534 and (804)232-2222.

I am completely new to SQL and this is over my head so any help would be awesome.

I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM abc
WHERE phones?????????
```

Comment: So the numbers are guaranteed to be in that format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) statement with a wildcard:

```
SELECT * 
FROM abc
WHERE trim(phones) like '(520)%'
```

Comment: @user2855405 Glad I could help! Don't worry we all start somewhere.

Comment: @user2855405 With this you have to make sure there are no characters preceding the area code (that includes stuff like spaces) or the query won't work.

Comment: @holodoc Good point!  I assumed the OP's format didn't include any leading spaces.  How would you handle that?  With a leading wildcard?

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox you could use `WHERE trim(phones) like '(520)%'`

Comment: You could also find rows with '520' in the 2nd thru 4th characters (sometimes this may be more efficient than LIKE). `WHERE substr(trim(phones),2,3) = '520'`

Comment: @Turophile Thanks for the suggestions, I used the `trim` function.